# Python CSV Row Loop

Tags: python, csv

I am very new to Python programming and decided on a small project to learn the language.

Basically I am trying to:

1. Read the first cell of a CSV file.
2. Ask if that cell value is "liked".
3. If liked, write to the column next to the cell on 1., "1".
4. Else, write "0".
5. Repeat on next row until end of list.

My code right now:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("mylist.csv"), delimiter=',')

data = []

for row in reader:
    data.append(row)

ask = (data[0][0])

ans = input("Do you like {}? ".format(ask))

if ans == ("y"):
        f = open('mylist.csv', 'r')
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        data = list(reader)
        f.close()
        data[0][1] = '1'
        my_new_list = open('mylist.csv', 'w', newline='')
        csv_writer = csv.writer(my_new_list)
        csv_writer.writerows(data)
        my_new_list.close()

else:
        f = open('mylist.csv', 'r')
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        data = list(reader)
        f.close()
        data[0][1] = '0'
        my_new_list = open('mylist.csv', 'w', newline='')
        csv_writer = csv.writer(my_new_list)
        csv_writer.writerows(data)
        my_new_list.close()
```

So basically, I am stuck trying to get the content of the next row.

FYI, I am looking to implement machine learning to this process.

First learning how to do this in a basic manner.

Any help is welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually you don't seem to realize the complexity of the task you have undertaken. Reading and writing to a CSV file at the same time is very very very hard. That's why people used fixed length records in the bad old days before RDBMS became common place

Comment: Don't try and write it back to the same file. Try to hold the updated version in memory (in lists and dicts etc) and write it to a file when you exit. You could create a new result file or overwrite the file.

Comment: I did not know the complexity of the task until I started hehe. But now I want to find the best way to finish it @e4c5 .

Comment: You are learning something that you will never use. learn to use an RDBMS instead.

Comment: I understand @PaulRooney . This was actually how I had the code written up first hand. But then I put everything together since I do not know how to add the value to the current "read" row.

Comment: I see, @e4c5 . Thank you. I will read on about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't read from and write to the same file/list/dict at the same time. If you do, references to data may change. You can start with something like this for your task. However, note that as the file grows you code becomes slower.

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("test.csv", 'r'), delimiter=',')
content = []

for row in reader:
    item = row[0]
    ans = raw_input("Do you like {}? ".format(item))

    if ans == 'y':
        content.append([item, 1])
    else:
        content.append([item, 0])

writer = csv.writer(open('test.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerows(content)
```

Comment: You are great, thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted. I knew what I wrote was exaggerated but did not know the way to reach it. Now I see how easy it was.

Answer (score 0):

In my last work with csv I opened the file so:

```html
import csv
with open(name) as csvfile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                for row in reader:
                        data.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the resultant csv file to contain all of the data from the input file but with the question results added in, you could use something like this.
It will insert you answer (0 or 1) after the first item in each record.

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("mylist.csv", 'r'), delimiter=',')
data = []

for row in reader:
    data.append(row)
for row in data:
    ans = raw_input("Do you like {}? ".format(row[0]))
    if ans == 'y':
        row[1:1] = "1"
    else:
        row[1:1] = "0"

writer = csv.writer(open('myresult.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerows(data)
```